# Flex - Save image with higher dpi

Tags: apache-flex, bitmapdata

In Flex, I am using graphics.codec.JPEGEncoder to save image files that are edited inside application (normal manipulations like brightness etc.) I am able to save files perfectly. What I want to know is that is there any way I can save the image with a better dpi? Say, for instance the image that is loaded and manipulated was originally of 72dpi, now can I save it with a dpi of 150 or 300 ? If so, how to do it.

Doesn't have to be using the JPEGEncoder, if there's any way to do it at all, like using any library etc, I am okay with it. Any suggestions?

Note: If it matters, I am using Bitmapdata to store the image and manipulations and saving the image with JPEGEncoder by supplying it's data as bytearray like below.

```
var imageBytes:ByteArray = encoder.encode(myBitmapData);
```

Comment: What is the DPI of your monitor?  Really to get a screenshot at a higher DPI than that you have to run it through some form of conversion process which adds more pixels.  When I was Editor in Chief of Flex Authority, we gave people this link: http://www.turbophoto.com/Photoshop-Tricks/screenshot-photoshop-trick/index.htm . I have no idea how to do such a conversion in AS3.

Comment: I'm fairly sure DPI has nothing to do with JPEG.  DPI is just a measurement for printing purposes.  The file you save will *never* be of a specific DPI (of course, there's metadata for that), but really what it comes down to is how big your image will become which can be calculated easily enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you say you want to save a 72 dpi image as 150 or 300 dpi image, then it should be in your case essentially an enlargement and you have to use something like [bicubic interpolation](http://www.clevr.com/blog/2008/resize-actionscript-bicubic-bilinear-interpolation/) for this.